# Python plot different variables on same y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to visualize many parameters over time. Basically, I want to plot datetime on x-axis, different parameters on y-axis.

My code:

```
df = 
index                     y1        y2         y3
2021-03-14 08:38:22   34.660422  6.278744  443.253277
2021-03-14 08:39:11   34.853815  6.267421  446.127032
2021-03-14 08:40:01   34.966101  6.338569  446.868933
2021-03-14 08:41:13   34.687784  6.339623  454.871855
2021-03-14 10:42:56  403.837103  9.091500  847.931740

# plot
plt.plot(df.index,df['y1'],'o')
plt.plot(df.index,df['y2'],'o')
plt.plot(df.index,df['y3'],'o')
plt.show()
```

It outputs the plot. The problem is, `y1` data dominates `y2` and we cannot clearly see the second column trend. How do I address this?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** You can plot y1 and y2 on different y axes so that the scale of one does not overwhelm the other one:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_ylabel("y1 data")
ax2.set_ylabel("y2 data")
ax1.plot(df.index,df.y1, color = 'red', label = 'y1')
ax2.plot(df.index, df.y2, color = 'blue', label = 'y2')
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax1.legend()
ax2.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you have more than two data columns with different orders of magnitude as in your updated question, you have two options:

**Option 2.** Create multiple subplots. By vertically stacking them, you can re-enforce the fact that they use the same x-axis.

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(len(df.columns),1)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_ylabel(df.columns[i])
    ax.plot(df.index,df.iloc[:,i], c = (random.random(),random.random(),random.random()))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.suptitle('Stacked Subplots')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Option 3.** You can scale all dataframe columns to the same order of magnitude, plot them is the same plot and include the scale factors in the legend.

```
def order_of_mag(num):
    return math.floor(math.log10(num))

min_order_of_mag = order_of_mag(min(df.min()))
column_scale_factors = [10 ** (order_of_mag(v) - min_order_of_mag) for v in df.min()]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    ax.plot(df.index, df[df.columns[i]]/column_scale_factors[i], label = f'{df.columns[i]} data x {column_scale_factors[i]}')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Scaled Y Data')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks fine and I am aware. When we have more than two variables and different magnitude? Also, I just edited my question to explain what I am looking for. Thanks